# Greasepencil Object Visible in Unwanted Parts

Tags: transparency, grease-pencil, shader-nodes

I am making this illustration of a 3D card and the effect that I want in the end is that it has some depth inside, so I made this folllowing setup:[image]

[image]
there's the box, and the different layers of greasepencil distributed inside. As you can see, they are not on the same level.

[image]

In the shader editor, used this above in both of the greasepencil objects, and this on the box (that doesn't have the front face, because the other face (which came from a different cube) is the frame:
[image]
to make the box insivible in the final render, but you still couldn't see whats inside.

But when I rendered the animation, the layer that is supposed to be inside, shows like this:
[image]

I tried making two separate greasepencils objects (one for the frame, another for the interior), but the final render, still does the same thing. How can this be solved? Did I do something wrong in the shader editor? I'm still new to blender, so I don't know how to make it.

Comment: Did you follow any specific tutorial or instructions or your are trying to figure it out yourself? Can you share your blend file for others to test?

Comment: I didn't follow any specific tutorial, I was just trying to apply the greasepencil principles that I learned on something new.  But I made this wetransfer link available for the file, so you can have access: https://we.tl/t-oVcPzqWTgh

Comment: Hi Isla, thanks for sharing the file. Your problem is much clearer now. In Properties Editor click on View Layer tab and in Passes > Data turn on the Z pass. This will solve your issue. Just a tip: Transform the "creature details" layer of your frame GP object at -0.5 on Y axis. This will make the bubbles appear in front of the character.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Why is this Z pass turned off when usually Im using the 3D space to use depth? that's weird

Comment: I am asking myself the same question - probably the option needs to be moved to the Grease Object settings instead of enabling Z pass globally. I suppose that Grease Pencil object is usually used as overlay of the 3D scene that needs to be always on top. Enabling Z Pass considers it as a real 2D object in 3D space.

Answer (score 0):

As it was discovered by Rumen, the solution was simply to enable the *Z Pass* on the DATA on View Layer Tab. In the next Grease Pencil projects, I will be needing to be aware of this to bring the desirable results.

[image]